# Is specific resistor and capacitor material type required for termination of high speed lines on PCB?

Tags: pcb, high-speed, termination

Most resistors will be metal film (aka thin film) and most capacitors will be ceramic (class II dielectric). Small components have less parasitive inductance than larger ones.

There are different type of terminations for high speed lines for impedance matching. Some use resistors while others could use capacitors with resistors. The question is, besides the value of the component used (resistor and also capacitor), to what extent does the material and frequency response (due to parasitics) matter when the resistor or capacitor is used for this application?

Comment: Definitely don't use wirewound resistors.

Comment: yes, I know that the wirewound types have high inductance, the name implies that it has a coil inside anyway.

Comment: Even non-inductively wound ones have pretty bad parasitics, though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every recent high speed *logic* design I've seen uses smd film resistors and similar format ceramic capacitors.

It is only with higher power RF lines that I've seen larger discrete components being used.

Comment: This implies that there is no special category of resistors and capacitors that have material and geometry design for use in high speed line termination. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, no special components